# How can I display a list in an x by y fashion?

Tags: css

What I want to do is similar to what is done here
http://www.starbucks.com/static/reference/styleguide/layout_promo_c.aspx

I have pored over the CSS and html trying to figure out how they manage to display the list in a 2 by 2 form.

What I've figured out is that they use an ordered list to organize it then have the contents of each block structured using the dl element. I managed to create 4 individual blocks but I can't get them in a 2 by 2 structure. I also can't seem to make the list inline despite setting the display property to it.

edit: changed poured to pored

Here is the relevant part of my css
http://pastebin.com/zLSNu29b
You might as well disregard it :/

Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't sound to hard... What I'd do is to have the four blocks inside a div limited by a width, and give the percent width for each of that four blocks, every of that floating to left.

Remember if you assign a 50% of width for one block the one to its right must have about a 48% of width, because you gotta include the margin(s) and padding(s), that's why sometimes when you have a div of 1000px and you assing 500px for a child and 500px for the other child, the second one is below of the first one.

Do you understand?

Answer (score 0):

The list items are floated left so that they'll line up side-by-side until they span the container width, then the next 2 drop down below the first 2, and so on.

They are able to use 50% width while still specifying some horizontal padding by applying `box-sizing: border-box;` to the list-items  which changes the way width is calculated to include border and padding within the width definition. This is a css3 property, so won't work in older browsers.